# Javascript multiple prototype functions - how to call one from another

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I've been working a lot lately on making cleaner Javascript code, and using objects with prototypes etc. But I'm confused on some points...

```
function TimeCard(){
    this.date               = new Date();
    this.pay_period_begin   = null;
    this.pay_period_end     = null; 
}
```

Here is my timecard object with some initial values. I have a bunch of functions that I've written and more to come that are part of that timecard and, if I understand correctly, they will be prototype functions. Here is some of what I have so far:

```
TimeCard.prototype = {         
    init : function(){
        this.pay_period_begin   = $("#pay_period_begin");
        this.pay_period_end     = $("#pay_period_end");
    },
    getTimeCardData : function(){
          //ajax request
    },
    selectAll : function(){
        this.getTimeCardData();
    }
    ...
};
```

My problem is that when I try to call `this.getTimeCardData()` it says that my object has no such method. I can obviously access the other variables because they are declared in my constructor, but I don't understand how prototype scopes I guess. So far I have gotten around this by using `tc.getTimeCardData()` instead of `this.getTimeCardData()`, with `tc` being the instance of my object declared outside - `var tc = new TimeCard();`. I'm sure that that's not the correct way to go about this, but what is?

Comment: can you show us the function where you call `this.getTimeCardData()` please ?

Comment: Yeah, it's already in the code shown under the `selectAll` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My problem is that when I try to call `this.getTimeCardData()` it says that my object has no such method.

It sounds like `this` is no longer referring to your instance. You'll have to show us the actual call for us to be sure, but in JavaScript, `this` is set primarily by how a function is *called*, not where it's defined, and so it's fairly easy for `this` to end up being something different.

Here's a hypothetical example:

```
TimeCard.prototype = {
    // ...
    doSomething: function() {
        // here, `this` probably refers to the timecard
        someArray.forEach(function() {
            this.getTimeCardData(); // <=== Problem, `this` has changed
        });
    }
    // ...
};
```

If I call `this.doSomething();` on a `TimeCard` object, within the call `this` will refer to the timecard. But within the `forEach` callback, `this` will no longer refer to the timecard. The same sort of thign happens with all kinds of callbacks; ajax, etc.

To work around it, you can remember `this` to a variable:

```
TimeCard.prototype = {
    // ...
    doSomething: function() {
        var thisCard = this;
        someArray.forEach(function() {
            thisCard.getTimeCardData(); // <=== Problem
        });
    }
    // ...
};
```

There are also various other ways to work around it, depending on your specific situation. For instance, you have `selectAll` calling `getTimeCardData`. But suppose `selectAll` is called with the wrong `this` value? In your comment, you said you were doing it like this:

```
$('#container').on('click', '#selectAll', tc.selectAll);
```

That means that when `selectAll` is called, `this` will refer to the DOM element, not to your object.

You have three options in that specific situation:

1. Since you're using jQuery, you can use `$.proxy`, which accepts a function and a value to use as `this`, and returns a new function that, when called, will call the original with `this` set to the desired value:

   ```
   $('#container').on('click', '#selectAll', $.proxy(tc.selectAll, tc));
   ```
2. Use ES5's `Function#bind`, which does the same thing. Note that IE8 and earlier don't have it unless you include an "ES5 shim" (hence my noting `$.proxy` above; you *know* you have that):

   ```
   $('#container').on('click', '#selectAll', tc.selectAll.bind(tc));
   ```
3. Use a closure *(don't let the name bother you, closures are not complicated)*:
   More *(on my blog)*:

   ```
   $('#container').on('click', '#selectAll', function() {
       tc.selectAll();
   });
   ```

In all of the above, you'll lose the benefit of `this` referring to the DOM element. In that particular case, you probably don't care, but if you did, you can get it from the event object's `currentTarget` property. For instance, this calls `tc.selectAll` with `this` referring to `tc` and passing in what *would* have been `this` (the DOM element you hooked the handler on) as the first argument:

```
$('#container').on('click', '#selectAll', function(e) {
    tc.selectAll(e.currentTarget);
});
```

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

---

Another, less likely, possibility relates to how you're updating `TimeCard.prototype`. The way you're doing it, it's possible to create objects via `new TimeCard()` *before* your code that replaces the `TimeCard.prototype` object runs, which means they'll have the old prototype.

In general, I strongly recommend **not** replacing the object automatically created for the `prototype` property of the constructor function. Instead, just *add to* the object already there, like this:

```
function TimeCard(){
    this.date               = new Date();
    this.pay_period_begin   = null;
    this.pay_period_end     = null; 
}
TimeCard.prototype.getTimeCardData = function(){
      //ajax request
};
// ...
```

Here's why: Timing. If you *replace* the object on the `prototype` property, any objects you create via `new TimeCard()` *before* you do that replacement will have the old prototype, not the new one.

I also recommend always creating these within a scoping function so you know that the declaration and the prototype additions happen at the same time:

```
var TimeCard = (function() {
    function TimeCard(){
        this.date               = new Date();
        this.pay_period_begin   = null;
        this.pay_period_end     = null; 
    }
    TimeCard.prototype.getTimeCardData = function(){
          //ajax request
    };
    // ...

    return TimeCard;
})();
```

...primarily because it prevents the timing issue.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Thanks. It does. In fact, people do. :-) There's an RSS feed linked in the top right, but any decent reader will auto-discover if you just post the address in. Drop me a note with the problem you're having? tj.crowder@farsightsoftware.com

Comment: epic answer just as usual

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to understand. Although neither of those were my problem I think - the actual call I was referring to is just in the `selectAll` function in my prototypes. So those prototypes couldn't see each other for some reason. But I do like that last example you gave, I'll have to try that.

Comment: @Tanner: That probably pushes the question out a level: How was `selectAll` being called? Because if `selectAll` were being used as a callback (event handler, ajax handler, `setTimeout` callback, etc.), then during the call to `selectAll`, `this` wouldn't be pointing at the object anymore.

Comment: You're right - here's the event handler: `$('#container').on('click', '#selectAll', tc.selectAll)` So what's the solution here?

Comment: @Tanner: Ah, good. I've updated the answer to give some specifics for that situation.

Comment: Thanks again. That makes sense. Is there a good, better, best option between the proxy, bind and closure?

Comment: @Tanner: Nine times out of ten, you already have a useful context you can close over, so I tend toward that. But where you don't, I'd probably lean toward having a shim and using `Function#bind`. But at that point, it's basically a style thing.